# Setting xticks to the middle of a given year with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to Python and visualization and am trying to get my plot to only display the xticks in the middle of each year (see my plot below). I have tried a couple of things with date_range but now my plot is displaying two xticks for each year, one for the beginning of the year and one for the middle of the year. How can I get rid of the xticks that are at the beginning of each year and only keep the ones at the middle of each year?

Here's my code and plot:

```
texasdrought['ValidStart']=pd.to_datetime(texasdrought['ValidStart'])
droughtMask = texasdrought[texasdrought['ValidStart'].dt.year.between(2005,2015)]

# Set the figure size
plt.figure(figsize = (30,16))

# Create a mask with the dates
dates = droughtMask["ValidStart"]

# Categorize droughts
droughtcat = {
    'D4 - Exceptional Drought': droughtMask["D4"],
    'D3 - Extreme Drought': droughtMask["D3"],
    'D2 - Severe Drought': droughtMask["D2"],
    'D1 - Moderate Drought': droughtMask["D1"],
    'D0 - Abnormally Dry': droughtMask["D0"]
}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(dates, droughtcat.values(), labels=droughtcat.keys(),colors=['#660000','#FF0000','#FF6600','#FFCC99','#FFFF00'])

# Format y-axis to percentages
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("'%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())

# Add legend location
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

# Add title to the stackplot
ax.set_title('Drought in Texas (2005-2015)')

ticks = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='6M')
plt.xticks(ticks)

# Add axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Drought Intensity')

# Save figure as DroughtPlot.jpg
fig.savefig('DroughtPlot.jpg')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Thank you.

Comment: Since you already have the ticks you want, you could simply try to change the `plt.xticks` line to `plt.xticks(ticks[1::2])`.

Comment: Thank you @jfaccioni!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

`ticks = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='A-JUN')` which will generate monthly dates ending in middle of each year at the last date of middle month.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2005-06-30', '2006-06-30', '2007-06-30', '2008-06-30',
               '2009-06-30', '2010-06-30', '2011-06-30', '2012-06-30',
               '2013-06-30', '2014-06-30', '2015-06-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-JUN')
```